# Pass variable into page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, puppeteer

I have searched for passing variables, but I'm not successful. It returns the 'data' as undefined. Please help me to fix this!

```
const details = (
      await Promise.allSettled(
        datas
          .map(async (data) => {
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            await page.goto(data.link, {
              waitUntil: "networkidle2",
            });
            return await page.evaluate((data) => {
              return {
                regular_price: document.querySelector(data.regular_price_class)
                  ? document.querySelector(data.regular_price_class).innerText.replace(/[\$,\D]/g, "")
                  : "",
                sale_price: document.querySelector(data.sale_price_class)
                  ? document.querySelector(data.sale_price_class).innerText.replace(/[\$,\D]/g, "")
                  : "",
                online_sale_price: document.querySelector(data.online_sale_price_class)
                  ? document.querySelector(data.online_sale_price_class).innerText.replace(/[\$,\D]/g, "")
                  : "",
                promotion: document.querySelector(data.promotion_class)
                  ? document.querySelector(data.promotion_class).innerText.replace(/[\$,\D]/g, "")
                  : "",
              };
            });
          }, data)
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're passing `data` as a second argument to `.map`, which doesn't make sense:

```
const details = (
    await Promise.allSettled(
      datas
        .map(async (data) => {
          // ...
        }, data)
    )
  )
```

Instead, you need to pass it to `page.evaluate`:

```
const details = (
    await Promise.allSettled(
      datas
        .map(async (data) => {
          const page = await browser.newPage();

          await page.goto(data.link, {
            waitUntil: "networkidle2",
          });
          return await page.evaluate((data) => {
            return {
              // ...
            };
          }, data);
        })
    )
  )
```

I'd also recommend a function for extracting prices to make things more DRY:

```
return page.evaluate((data) => {
    const getPrice = selector => (document.querySelector(selector)?.innerText || '').replace(/[\$,\D]/g, "");
  return {
      regular_price: getPrice(data.regular_price_class),
      sale_price: getPrice(data.sale_price_class),
      online_sale_price: getPrice(data.online_sale_price_class),
      promotion: getPrice(data.promotion_class),
  };
}, data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This took me all yesterday. My bad!